# Align row header text to center in gridx

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx

How can i align a row header to display heading in center in gridx. Am using gridx with dojo.

here is my structure

```
var gridLayout =  [
             {
              name: "id",
              field: "id",
              width:'20px'
             },
             {
             name: "Name",
             field: "Name"
            }
                ]
```

I want to align grid header to the center of the cell.Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS to Grid header.

```
.dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
text-align: center !important;
}
```